# Forcing specific plot symbols for points in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pch

I am trying to specify manually, the shape of data points in `r ggplot2` but can't seem to get it to work. Below is a sample example

```
p.est<- c(1.65, 1.55, 0.70, 1.61, 1.25)
lcl<-c(1.25, 1.10, 0.50, 1.20, 1.02)
ucl<-c(2.20, 2.05, 0.90, 2.20, 1.50)
toy.data <- tibble(zc = zc, p.est = p.est, p.lcl = p.lcl, p.ucl = p.ucl)
```

Assume I want two types of plot symbols for the five points, I use `scale_shape_manual()` in `ggplot2` but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my sample code and the resulting plot attached. I'm trying to modify so the plot symbols for the points correspond to `5` which is a diamond and `16` which is a circle.

```
ggplot(toy.data, aes(zc,  p.est, ymin = p.lcl, ymax = p.ucl)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(5, 16, 5, 5, 16))+
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.1))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1)+
  ylim(0.5, 2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the `zc` variable in the data generating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `shape = factor(p.est)`. Otherwise `scale_shape` doesn't apply to anything.

```
zc    <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
p.est <- c(1.65, 1.55, 0.70, 1.61, 1.25)
p.lcl   <-c(1.25, 1.10, 0.50, 1.20, 1.02)
p.ucl   <-c(2.20, 2.05, 0.90, 2.20, 1.50)

toy.data <- tibble(zc = zc, 
                   p.est = p.est, 
                   p.lcl = p.lcl, 
                   p.ucl = p.ucl)

ggplot(toy.data, aes(zc,  p.est, ymin = p.lcl, ymax = p.ucl, shape = factor(p.est))) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(5, 16, 5, 5, 16)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  ylim(0.5, 2.5)
```

**EDITED** Follow up question

```
toy.data <- tibble(zc = zc, 
                   p.est = p.est, 
                   p.est.x = c("A","B","A","A","B"),
                   p.lcl = p.lcl, 
                   p.ucl = p.ucl)

ggplot(toy.data, aes(zc,  p.est, ymin = p.lcl, ymax = p.ucl, shape = p.est.x)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(5, 16)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  ylim(0.5, 2.5)
```

Comment: To preserve the ordering of the plotted points, we also need to add levels to the `factor()`. That is  `shape = factor(p.est, levels = unique(p.est))` . Otherwise the ordering may not be as in the original dataset.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: Is their a way I can add the legend such that it only contains the two unique shape values? Like only have a legend with a diamond and a circle instead of all five (default) corresponding to the  length of the shape factor?

Comment: Usually you can use `limits` in `scale_shape`, but you can use it in this case. You probably want to attach a real factor to "p.est" since what you seem to want is to associate certain results with a category. See edited answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do - associate certain values with a category. The solution you provide with adding the character vector `p.est.x` works for this particular toy example. However, if instead of `p.est.x=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B')` we have `p.est.x=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B')` then the resulting plot only assumes one plot symbol corresponding to the shape for `A`. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I meant that if the first two points belong to the same category/shape- e.g. `c('A', 'A')` and `c(5, 5)` then for some reason `r` ignores other plot symbols. I'm not sure why it behaves like this though. I only have a few set of points that I'm trying to plot and the kind of approach may work here but I do agree adding the values manually may not be the way to go for a larger dataset.

Comment: I got it! The values for `scale_shape_manual()` are a vector of values for the symbols in the graph. You have two categories, so the vector should only have two items. The extra items will be ignored. The proper syntax is `scale_shape_manual(values = c("5","16"))` I'll edit my answer to reflect this. Sorry, should have noticed this earlier.

Comment: Awesome! I get the logic now. Thanks!